# Concatenando Palabras en Java

Tags: java

Tengo este código en Java que trabaje para mi clase, pero no me esta funcionando.

Consiste en pedirle al usuario una palabra, y otra, hasta que ingrese un campo vació, y el resultado se concatene.

Es un código muy fácil, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

¿Como lo ven?

```
public class ConcatenaPalabras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.println("Dame una cadena");
        String cadUsuario = sc.next();

        String concatenar = "";

        while (!cadUsuario.isEmpty()) { 

            concatenar += cadUsuario; 

            System.out.println("Dame una cadena");
            cadUsuario = sc.next();
        }
        System.out.println(concatenar);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es error que te muestra o que es lo que te falla?

Comment: He probado el código que has indicado y no me da error. ¿Podrías indicar que te sucede en el tuyo? Indícalo editando la pregunta por favor.

Comment: En realidad tu código no tiene ningún problema.

Comment: El problema era que necesitaba utilizar el metodo nextLine() en vez de next. Muy amable a todos

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Yo respondería con los ojos. Edita tu pregunta indicando cuál es la pregunta o el problema exacto, de lo contrario se cerrará.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así como lo has escrito, pulsar enter en la consola sin introducir nada no te va a devolver nunca una cadena vacía, con lo que tu while no terminará nunca.

Para poder recibir una cadena vacía, tienes que usar la función nextLine en vez de next para obtener los datos tecleados por el usuario.

Tu programa quedaría así:

```
public class ConcatenaPalabras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.println("Dame una cadena");
        String cadUsuario = sc.nextLine();

        String concatenar = "";

        while (!cadUsuario.isEmpty()) { 

            concatenar += cadUsuario; 

            System.out.println("Dame una cadena");
            cadUsuario = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(concatenar);
    }
}
```

Comment: El código de la pregunta funciiona sin problema, en realidad no mporta si usa sc.nextLine() y sc.next() , ambos van a terminar el bucle.

Comment: Ahi si funciona! Excelente!!

Comment: @Jorgesys no se porque, pero utilizando sc.nextLine() si funciono. El bucle while con el metodo next() no terminaba de salir nunca

Comment: nextLine no devuelve el delimitador y next sí. Por eso el retorno de next no es una cadena vacía y la función isEmpty retorna siempre false. [This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())